# Where Statement

Tags: parallelization, conditional

Is there a "parallel" way to perform these operations?

```
Indices = {}
For[i = 1, i <= Length[w], i++,
 If[w[[i]] < 0, AppendTo[Indices, i]]]
```

Which gives a list of the Indices where the list w is negative. This is a little slow.

Is there a faster cleaner way to get the same answer? This is essentially the Fortran 90 where statement.

Comment: `indices = Select[w, Negative]` -- not parallel, but reasonably efficient.  Or `Pick[w, Negative[w]]`.

Comment: If you need the indices, not the elements, use `Position[w, _?Negative]`.  Parallelization is not the best or fastest approach for this task in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs. "Position" is what I needed. I was using "parallel" loosely, as in what was once upon a time called "SIMD" (single instructions multiple data).

Comment: @JEP In that case, for good performance, you can try `Pick[Range@Length[w], UnitStep[w], 0]`.  I think this will be the fastest way to get the *indices* (but depending what you want to do afterwards, using the indices may not be the fastest solution).

Answer (score 9):

I suppose it's better to make my comment into an answer, per SE policy.  The slowness is due to `AppendTo`, which has been pointed out [by many others](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=AppendTo+slow) before, as well as in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AppendTo.html#713662435).

To get the *indices*,

```
indices = Pick[Range[Length[w]], UnitStep[w]]
```

will be fast.

Reasons for starting variable names with a [lower-case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=lower+case+variable+is%3Aa) letter instead of a [capital](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=capital+variable+is%3Aa) have been discussed before, too.

---

**Original answer**

[I misread what was being stored. Oops.]

Two possibilities:

```
indices = Select[w, Negative]

indices = Pick[w, Negative[w]]
```

`Pick` will be faster on large [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).  Or as [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) points out, it will be even faster if both arguments are packed:

```
indices = Pick[w, UnitStep[w]]
```

Comment: Actually `Pick` will be fastest if both arguments are packed, i.e. `Pick[w, UnitStep[w], 0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison:
Consider following approaches:

```
f[x_] := Cases[x, _?Negative];
g[x_] := Select[x, Negative];
h[x_] := Pick[x, UnitStep[x], 0];
k[x_?Negative] := x;
k[x_] := Sequence[];
```

Testing on:

```
list = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^6];
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Szabolcs, we could parallelize by partitioning the list and using `ParallelMap`.
Assuming `$KernelCount` is not zero,

Data:

```
w = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Prime[10^6]];
```

Without parallelizing:

```
First@Timing[a1 = Flatten@Position[w, _?Negative];]
```

> 17.097710

Parallelizing:

```
First@Timing[
  a2 = With[
     {
      n = Quotient[Length[w], $KernelCount]
      },
     Flatten[
      Range[0, Length[w], n]
       + ParallelMap[Flatten[Position[#, _?Negative]] &, 
        Partition[w, n, n, 1, {}]]
      ]
     ];]
```

> 7.441248

```
a1 == a2
```

> True